# Click event not working while position in css is absolute in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Code is as follows:

```js
$('#navigationLink').on('touchstart', function() {
  //debugger;
  var navi = $(this).find('p').attr('navi');
  if (navi == 'tryit') {
    alert('try');
  }
  if (navi == 'view') {
    alert('view');
  }
  if (navi == 'next') {
    alert('next');
  }
});
```

```css
.pos_next {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigationLink" class="col-xs-12 align_center pos_next">
  <p class="page_4_titles font_futura_bold clr_black" navi="next">Next Question</p>
</div>
```

Please check in fiddle for more info https://jsfiddle.net/Lf0f8a4u/

Comment: It doesn't work on click because you only added a `touchstart` event handler. If you include a click handler it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf0f8a4u/1/. Also, for future reference please include *all* relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the computer, you dont have the event `touchstart`. It is `mousedown` or `click`.

```js
$('#navigationLink').on('click', function() {
  debugger;
  var navi = $(this).find('p').attr('navi');
  if (navi == 'tryit') {
    alert('try');
  }
  if (navi == 'view') {
    alert('view');
  }
  if (navi == 'next') {
    alert('next');
  }

});
```

```css
.pos_next {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigationLink" class="col-xs-12 align_center pos_next">
  <p class="page_4_titles font_futura_bold clr_black" navi="next">Next Question</p>
</div>
```

**Information**

---

If you want to have a compatible version for the computer and the mobile browsers you could use `$('').on('touchstart click', function...`.

The difference between `touchstart` and `click` is, that the `touchstart` is fired directly in mobile browsers as `click` on your computer. The `click`-Event has a 300ms delay on the iPhone Safari, because they check if the user want to doubble click, for the `zoom gesture`.

Comment: @Surendra you're welcome. You may mark it as the answer, so other can see that its correct :-)